# Regarding file upload control in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I have a Popup control and it contains
 a 'file Upload' Control and Attach' link Button'  , 'SUBMIT" and 'CANCEL' button

when a user selects a file and when he clicks attach button   " the attached file and a link button 'Remove' should appear dynamically.
and when user selects another file to attach    " the attached file and a link button to remove the link should appear below the first uploaded file.
like this user can attach 10 files each of size 3GB.

Answer (score 0):

you describe a functionality that isn't built in. You have to put, in example, a asp:DataList or asp:GridView, which being filled with the files attached by the user.

You may store the file info in a database, which populates the asp control. The control itself have may have fields that get the name of the file, upload date and a button that calls a method that removes the file (from disc and info from database).

You would please give a better specification of what kind of help you asking for. Idelogy, functional cut'n pasteable code and so on.

You also have to take in mind, you wroted about 3GB sizes, that there are built-in file size limitations that you have to override. Search StackOverflow for maxRequestLength for more info.

```
 <configuration>   
   <system.web>
     <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="xxx" />
   </system.web>
 </configuration>
```